# How to use apache commons io for Java in Linux terminal?

Tags: java, linux, apache, classpath, apache-commons

I tried to compile (using only javac filename.java) a class with the following import:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

This threw an error: "package org.apache.commons.io does not exist".
So after some googling I realized that I need some sort of commons-io .jar file and that I can try to compile with something like,

```
javac -cp .:common-io-xx.jar filename.java
```

I guess the xx part is a placehodler meant to be replaced when I know the proper name of the file that I'm trying to add to my classpath (tell me if I'm wrong).

I tried finding this .jar file but on the following site:(http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) I could only find some .tar files which as far as I could see did not contain any .jar files. Thus I need help with two things:

1) Where can I find the correct file containing the source code I need to use the commons-io library?

2) Upon finding that file, how do I successfully compile (and run) my program in the Linux terminal?

Please note that I am completely new to the concept of classpath and need help with how to apply this in the terminal.

I know similar questions have been asked before, but none so elementary that I could use their answers, I'm afraid.

Comment: Download the binaries (either the tar or the zip file). They contain both the jar and the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't need the source code of commons-io in order to compile your code. As you have been trying to do, you just need the commons-io jar file. If you are interested learning how the code works in that particular jar, a quick google search will bring you to this github repo: https://github.com/apache/commons-io

2) The files from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi are compressed files. The easiest option for you is to download commons-io-X.Y-bin.zip (replace X and Y with whatever version you are looking for). Unzip the zip file you downloaded (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156261/unzipping-a-gz-file-without-removing-the-gzipped-file), then compile with the command you have above (make sure your classpath, source file locations are correct).